# Override GetType Method on ascx usercontrol

Tags: vb.net, webforms, user-controls, ascx, aspx-user-control

I want to override Gettype method on ascx usercontroll, to returna specific type to able compare with TypeOf.

My Current Aproach is on my usercontroll add a property and :

```
   Private Property Type As App.Controls.DropdownCustom
Public Shadows Function [GetType]() As Type
    Return Type.GetType()
End Function
```

But he still return current type of usercontroll name.

Comment: Of what type is `App.Controls`?

Comment: App.Controls is a namespace with another class example mycustomnamecontroll